# Get key & value from associative array using numeric index

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array:

```
$array = array(
     '001' => '555',
     '002' => '666',
     '003' => '777'
);
```

I wish to get the key & value using number index

```
$key = $array[0];
$value = $array[0][];
```

I am using a number index as the size of the array when executed will be unknown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `array_keys` to get the keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$key = $keys[0];
$value = $array[$key];
```